# Alignment of individual rows in left-justified system of equations

Tags: cases, alignment, justification

I typeset a general system of equations, which involved some "vertical" dots. But I can't figure out how to make those dots appears in the center. Moreover, I actually want to make two streams of vertical dots. Would appreciate some help.

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
u_{1,t}=\nabla\cdot D(u_{1})\nabla u_{1,t}+f_1(c_1, \dots, c_m, u_1, \dots, u_n)\\ 
\vdots \\
u_{n,t}=\nabla\cdot D(u_{n})\nabla u_{n,t}+f_2(c_1, \dots, c_m, u_1, \dots, u_n)\\ 
c_{1,t}=\Delta c_1-g_1(c_1, \dots, c_m, u_1, \dots, u_n)\\ 
\vdots \\
c_{m,t}=\Delta c_m-g_m(c_1, \dots, c_m, u_1, \dots, u_n)\\
\end{cases}\tag{II}
\end{equation}
```

[image: system of equations]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not uses `cases` for this, which is better suited for use on the right-hand side of an equation.  Rather I would use an `aligned` block, aligning on the equality signs, and enclosed in a

```
\left\{  ...  \right.
```

pair to produce the left brace.  MadyYuvi's suggestion to use `\vdotswithin` is also a good aid.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \left\{
    \begin{aligned}
      u_{1,t}&=\nabla\cdot D(u_{1})\nabla u_{1,t}+f_1(c_1, \dots, c_m,
      u_1, \dots, u_n)\\
      &\vdotswithin{=} \\
      u_{n,t}&=\nabla\cdot D(u_{n})\nabla u_{n,t}+f_2(c_1, \dots, c_m,
      u_1, \dots, u_n)\\
      c_{1,t}&=\Delta c_1-g_1(c_1, \dots, c_m, u_1, \dots, u_n)\\
      &\vdotswithin{=} \\
      c_{m,t}&=\Delta c_m-g_m(c_1, \dots, c_m, u_1, \dots, u_n)\\
    \end{aligned}
  \right.
  \tag{II}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `\vdotswithin` tag which comes along with the package `mathtools`, and the codes are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
u_{1,t}=\nabla\cdot D(u_{1})\nabla u_{1,t}+f_1(c_1, \dots, c_m, u_1, \dots, u_n)\\ 
\vdotswithin{u_{n,t}=\nabla\cdot D(u_{n})\nabla u_{n,t}+f_2(c_1, \dots, c_m, u_1, \dots, u_n)} \\
u_{n,t}=\nabla\cdot D(u_{n})\nabla u_{n,t}+f_2(c_1, \dots, c_m, u_1, \dots, u_n)\\ 
c_{1,t}=\Delta c_1-g_1(c_1, \dots, c_m, u_1, \dots, u_n)\\ 
\vdotswithin{u_{n,t}=\nabla\cdot D(u_{n})\nabla u_{n,t}+f_2(c_1, \dots, c_m, u_1, \dots, u_n)} \\
c_{m,t}=\Delta c_m-g_m(c_1, \dots, c_m, u_1, \dots, u_n)\\
\end{cases}\tag{II}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Please read the documentation of `mathtools` package, `page number 22` for further details

Comment: I'm using Kile (XeLaTeX). For some reason it complains when I try to compile a file with it:

l.263 \vdotswithin\\
                    
! Misplaced \cr.
\reserved@b ->\ifnum 0=`{\fi }${}\cr

Comment: @sequence The mentioned error may be due to version issue, please update with the current setup and try...

Comment: Thanks, it looks like it is working now.

Comment: Glad to hear...